# Rails Carrierwave "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload, carrierwave

Trying to wrap my head around the first attempt at uploading an image via CarrierWave. I can see data being sent, but then in the console I also see a BEGIN and a ROLLBACK in the action.
So, here's what I have so far

Controller

```
 class PhotosController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_photo, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

def index
@photos = Photo.all
end

def new
@photos = Photo.new
end

def create
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params)

if @photo.save
  redirect_to photos_path, notice: "The photo #{@photo.name} has been uploaded."
else
  render "new"
end
end

private
def photo_params
params.require(:photo).permit(:name, :image, :id)
end

def set_photo
 @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

FORM

```
  <div class="well">
  <%= form_for Photo.new, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :image %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

MODEL

```
 class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
 end
```

UPLOADER is pretty much as generated, storage is file and it uses MiniMagick and enabled the thumb version

Now, when I click the submit button, I see this in the console:

```
Started POST "/photos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-14 22:11:25 +0200
Processing by PhotosController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"Aj4CyJLaxh439igdVYJ60Pz9TqLzuvPVfkh903YAcaVuIqU8bKmX0zrgbL/GvnabcQ7i/hsqWxwvG1NRQO16JA==", "photo
"=>{"name"=>"fdsfds", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa96f1d0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart2
0170914-4696-1pwrynm.jpg>, @original_filename="Clipboard02.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[
image]\"; filename=\"Clipboard02.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, 
"commit"=>"Save"}
(1.0ms)  BEGIN 
(0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
```

And on the page where I am running the upload, it returns to the new form and thi text appears at the bottom

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"....(manuallyremoved)==", "photo"=><ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"fdsfds", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa96f1d0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Andrea/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170914-4696-1pwrynm.jpg>, @original_filename="Clipboard02.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[image]\"; filename=\"Clipboard02.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Save", "controller"=>"photos", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

So what is actually causing the permitted:false in this case?
I also noticed that there is a folder created in my public/uploads/tmp and the image is actually saved in that folder

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before doing `@photo.save` we need to do `@photo.valid?` then check the error messages `@photo.errors.full_messages`

you can either check this with a binding pry or puts this messages to the console

probably some fields are missing and for this reason it is rolling back

```
def create
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
# set hear a binding.pry or
@photo.valid?
puts @photo.errors.full_messages    

if @photo.save
  redirect_to photos_path, notice: "The photo #{@photo.name} has been uploaded."
else
  render "new"
end
end
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried adding one of those debugger lines found on another site, but guess I was doing it wrong. Now it turns out the issue is due the fact that I enabled thumbnails in the uploader so I have to figure out why that is creating problems. One step ahead though. Thanks for the good tip Fabrizio!

Comment: @Andrea if you need more help ask a new question with the details of the problem then send me the link so that I can read it and try to help you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Fabrizio Actually I just posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46268538/rails-couldnt-find-nested-resource-with-id