# Rails: Couldn't find nested resource with ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a 3 layers nested model:
galleries -> has many albums -> has many photos

When I try to add a new album from here
http://localhost:3000/galleries/1/albums/new
I am getting

> "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AlbumsController#create   Couldn't
>   find Gallery with 'id'="

Albums model:

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :gallery
 has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

Gallery model

```
   class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :albums
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums
 end
```

Routes

```
....
 resources :galleries do
  resources :albums 
 end
resources :photos, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
 resources :photos, only: [:index]
 resources :albums  do
   resources :photos, :controller => "albums"
 end
```

In order to get to the page to create album, I call it like this from within the Show page for the gallery
      <%= link_to 'New Album', new_gallery_album_path(@galleries.id) %>
This leads to the correct page which does have the ID 1 of the gallery in the link

But in the controller, I don't really understand why the gallery_id is hanlded as a nil

```
  def new
   @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
   @album = Album.new
   @photos = @album.photos.build
  end
 def create
  @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
  @album = Album.new(album_params)

  respond_to do |format|
```

...

I can paste the rest of the controller, but now the error is pointing at the line in the create function
@gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
Why does this work ok within the NEW but not for the create?

Answer (score 2):

Actually figured it out after I asked. In the form, I was only calling

```
  %= form_for @album], :html => { :mutiplart...
```

But after changing it to

```
  <%= form_for [@gallery,@album], :html => { :mu
```

It worked